# Access Query create 1 instead of 3

Tags: sql, ms-access, merge

I have the following 3queries from one table. The different is the criteria([ReceiptYesNo]) in each query.

```
Query No1 - NO Criteria:
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
SELECT Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
FROM tblExpenses
GROUP BY Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy")
ORDER BY Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
PIVOT Month([ExpensesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

Query No2 - Criteria [ReceiptYesNo] = YES:
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
SELECT Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
FROM tblExpenses
WHERE (((tblExpenses.ReceiptYesNo)="YES"))   <=== See Here ===
GROUP BY Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy")
ORDER BY Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
PIVOT Month([ExpensesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

Query No3 - Criteria [ReceiptYesNo] = NO:
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
SELECT Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
FROM tblExpenses
WHERE (((tblExpenses.ReceiptYesNo)="NO"))   <=== See Here ===
GROUP BY Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy")
ORDER BY Format([ExpensesDate],"yyyy") DESC 
PIVOT Month([ExpensesDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Is it possible to create one query that have 3?

Thank you.

Comment: Which are the values "tblExpenses.ReceiptYesNo" can take? In case there only the 3 cases, then leave the criterium out.

Comment: "tblExpenses.ReceiptYesNo" can have Yes or No. Sum [Price] in No1, sum [Price] where [ReceiptYesNo]=Yes in No2, sum [Price] where [ReceiptYesNo]=No in No3. For example, the output for Month-1 in No1 is 10, the output for Month-1 in No2 is 8 and the output for Month-1 in No2 is 2. So [Price] forMonth-1 is 8+2=10 (Yes+No=Total).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION between each one - as long as the columns are the same

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp